# How can I shuffle an array and put them into buffered images?

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

Basically I'm making a domino game in Java; however I'm pretty new and can't figure out how to shuffle the dominoes up using arrays and buffered Images.

This code here is setting up the arrays for each hand and an array with each domino piece. Keep in mind that I am not using an AI for this domino game;
the program runner will just play as each player.

```
static String [] hand1 = new String[7];
static String [] hand2 = new String[7];
static String [] hand3 = new String[7];
static String [] hand4 = new String[7];
static String[] allDominoes = {"00","01","02","03","04","05","06","11","12","13","14","15","16","22","23",
          "24","25","26","33","34","35","36","44","45","46","55","56","66"};
```

This is what I tried to use to shuffle the dominoes and put them into each hand array:

```
public static void newRound() // start a new round; shuffle the dominoes; hand them out
{
    
Arrays.fill(hand1, null);
Arrays.fill(hand2, null);
Arrays.fill(hand3, null);
Arrays.fill(hand4, null);

String[] shuffledDominos = new String[28];
List<String> shuffled = Arrays.asList(allDominoes);

Collections.shuffle(shuffled);

shuffled.toArray(shuffledDominos);  

    int pos = 0;
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        hand1[pos] = shuffledDominos[j];
        pos++;
    }
    pos = 0;
    for (int y = 7; y < 14; y++)
    {
        hand2[pos] = shuffledDominos[y];
        pos++;
    }
    pos = 0;
    for (int x = 14; x < 21; x++)
    {
        hand3[pos] = shuffledDominos[x];
        pos++;
    }
    pos = 0;
    for (int z = 21; z < 28; z++)
    {
        hand4[pos] = shuffledDominos[z];
        pos++;
    }
```

However I think this part is completely wrong and there must be a better way of doing this since I'm not sure how to actually proceed from here on out.

This is assigning each domino Image the domino pngs.

```
public DominoPanel() 
{
    
    try
    {
        dom00 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/00.png"));
        dom01 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/01.png"));
        dom02 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/02.png"));
        dom03 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/03.png"));
        dom04 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/04.png"));
        dom05 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/05.png"));
        dom06 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/06.png"));
        dom11 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/11.png"));
        dom12 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/12.png"));
        dom13 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/13.png"));
        dom14 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/14.png"));
        dom15 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/15.png"));
        dom16 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/16.png"));
        dom22 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/22.png"));
        dom23 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/23.png"));
        dom24 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/24.png"));
        dom25 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/25.png"));
        dom26 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/26.png"));
        dom33 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/33.png"));
        dom34 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/34.png"));
        dom35 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/35.png"));
        dom36 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/36.png"));
        dom44 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/44.png"));
        dom45 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/45.png"));
        dom46 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/46.png"));
        dom55 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/55.png"));
        dom56 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/56.png"));
        dom66 = ImageIO.read(DominoPanel.class.getResource("/Image/66.png"));
        
    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {
        
    }
```

I know I probably didn't explain this well so I will try to summarize it here as best as I can. I need to be able to assign a random domino to each player and then print them out in a JPanel using buffered Images.

Comment: Create a method that reads your input files into your ArrayList. You just pass in the image number as a parameter and then build the filename dynamically so you can read the file. Creating 66 variables is wrong and too hard to maintain. if you have to repeat the code 66 times. Then you shuffle the ArrayList. Then you iterate through the ArrayList and assign an image to each player. As you assign the image you remove it from the ArrayList..

Comment: @camickr that actually helps a lot, makes more sense than what I was doing, thanks. But I'm a little confused how would I pass the image number as a parameter and then build a filename from that?

Comment: `String filename = "/Image/" + imageNumber + ".png";`, where "imageNumber" is the int parameter passed to the method.

Comment: Shouldn’t the last element of the allDominoes array be "66"?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' yes it should, sorry I don't know how I accidentally left that one out.